# Hydraulics sluice gates and hydraulic jumps

Tags: civil-engineering, hydraulics

I was wondering if anyone has an understanding on hydraulic jumps and sluice gates?

Why can you only use the energy equation for before and after the sluice gate? Why not at two points after the sluice gate e.g after sluice gate and before the hydraulic jump occurs?

Comment: Well covered in text books.

Answer (score 0):

An hydraulic jump is localized turbulence that dissipates kinetic energy. To understand how much kinteic energy requires a knowledge of the potential energy before the gate and after the gate to calculate the hydraulic jump wave celerity. Understanding the subcritical flow change to supercritical flow allows calulation of the hydraulic jump returning flow to subcritical again. Measurments taken after the sluice only show the supercrital flow and have no meaning.

Fluid Mechanics, R. C. Hibbler, Pearson; an excellent textbook for studying this.